# Summing values of Hive array types

Tags: arrays, hadoop, aggregate, hive, aggregation

Hive has this pretty nice Array type that is very useful in theory but when it comes to practice I found very little information on how to do any kind of opeartions with it.
We store a serie of numbers in an array type column and need to SUM them in a query, preferably from n-th to m-th element. Is it possible with standard HiveQL or does it require a UDF or customer mapper/reducer?

Note: we're using Hive 0.8.1 in EMR environment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd write a simple `UDF` for this purpose. You need to have `hive-exec` in your build path.
E.g In case of `Maven`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
  <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

A simple raw implementation would look like this:

```
package com.myexample;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;

public class SubArraySum extends UDF {

    public IntWritable evaluate(ArrayList<Integer> list, 
      IntWritable from, IntWritable to) {
        IntWritable result = new IntWritable(-1);
        if (list == null || list.size() < 1) {
            return result;
        }

        int m = from.get();
        int n = to.get();

        //m: inclusive, n:exclusive
        List<Integer> subList = list.subList(m, n);

        int sum = 0;
        for (Integer i : subList) {
            sum += i;
        }
        result.set(sum);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Next, build a jar and load it in Hive shell:

```
hive> add jar /home/user/jar/myjar.jar;
hive> create temporary function subarraysum as 'com.myexample.SubArraySum';
```

Now you can use it to calculate the sum of the array you have.

E.g:

Let's assume that you have an input file having tab-separated columns in it :

```
1   0,1,2,3,4
2   5,6,7,8,9
```

Load it into mytable:

```
hive> create external table mytable (
  id int,
  nums array<int>
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/user/hadoopuser/hive/input';
```

Execute some queries then:

```
hive> select * from mytable;
1   [0,1,2,3,4]
2   [5,6,7,8,9]
```

Sum it in range m,n where **m=1, n=3**

```
hive> select subarraysum(nums, 1,3) from mytable;
3
13
```

Or

```
hive> select sum(subarraysum(nums, 1,3)) from mytable;
16
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer above is quite well explained. I am posting a very simple implementation of the UDF.

```
package com.ak.hive.udf.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;

    public final class ArraySumUDF extends UDF {
        public int evaluate(ArrayList<Integer>arrayOfIntegers,int startIndex,int endIndex) {
            // add code to handle all index problem
                    int sum=0;
            int count=startIndex-1;
            for(;count<endIndex;count++){
                sum+=arrayOfIntegers.get(count);
            }
            return sum;
        }
    }
```

Also posting the table creation and other queries.

```
create table table1 (col1 int,col2 array<int>)ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '~' STORED AS TEXTFILE;

load data local inpath '/home/ak/Desktop/hivedata' into table table1;
```

My input file would look like

1,3~5~8~5~7~9
2,93~5~8~5~7~29
3,3~95~8~5~27~9
4,3~5~58~15~7~9
5,3~25~8~55~7~49
6,3~25~8~15~7~19
7,3~55~78~5~7~9

I have created a jar of my UDF, I add the jar to hive using the following command

```
add jar file:///home/ak/Desktop/array.jar;
```

Then I create temporary function as shown

```
create temporary function getSum as 'com.ak.hive.udf.test.ArraySumUDF';
```

Perform a sample query as below,

```
select col1,getSum(col2,1,3) from table1;
```

This should solve the very basic need. In case if this is not what the problem statement is, please respond back so that I can help you with again.